# Ionic 3 firebase Can't show user profile picture taken with camera (android)

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, camera

I would like to let the user take a picture with the camera and use it as new profile pic. To take the photo, I use this function:

```
capture(){
    this.camera.getPicture({
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    }).then(imageData => {
        this.myPhoto = imageData;
        this.uploadPhoto();
    }, error => {
        console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

    this.api.updateUserPhoto(this.myPhotoURL);
}
```

where `uploadPhoto()` is

```
private uploadPhoto(): void {
    this.myPhotosRef.child(this.generateUUID()).child('myPhoto.png')
    .putString(this.myPhoto, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/png' })
    .then((savedPicture) => {
        this.myPhotoURL = savedPicture.downloadURL;
    });
}
```

and `generateUUUID()` is

```
private generateUUID(): any {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
}
```

The camera is open correctly on the phone, and the image is saved in the gallery, but the profile of the user is not updated with the photo; to update the user profile, I use the function found on firebase documentation, that is:

```
updateUserPhoto(photo: any){
    var user =  firebase.auth().currentUser;
    user.updateProfile({
        displayName: user.displayName,
        photoURL: photo
    }).then(function() {
        // Update successful.
    }, function(error) {
        // An error happened.
    });
}
```

This is the function that is called in the method `capture` that I've posted at the beginning, to which I pass the photoUrl generated.
At the time a new user registers to the app, a default picture is uploaded as profile picture, and it is shown correctly in the `<ion-img>` element; whenever I try to change it by using the camera, after taking the picture, the `<ion-img>` shows a blank content. That makes me think that the photo was actually updated, so there must be a problem with the URL generated.

Comment: Do you see the correct image the next time you use the app?

Comment: Nope, it still displays the blank content

Comment: Try moving the call to `updateUserPhoto`, to the end inside the `then`-callback in `uploadPhoto`.

Comment: moved bu nothing changed :\ I've tried to logout and login back but it is still empty

Comment: Have you looked in the Firebase console to see if the picture is uploaded correctly?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how to check it. I've tried going to Authentication tab, where there's the list of registered user, but I don't know how to check if there's a photo uploaded. It just show the email, UID etc

Comment: Check the Storage  tab.

Comment: There are no files there!

Comment: Then you have to debug your code to see if you have the desired values at the right places. Start by checking what `savedPicture` contains.